# remove invalidAttributes in sails

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I am using sails(v0.11)

I have installed `sails-hook-validation` in my application.

```
validationMessages: {
    email: {
      required: 'Email is required',
      email: 'Provide valid email address',
      unique: 'Email address is already taken'
    },
    username: {
      required: 'Username is required'
    }
}
```

And added the above code to my model.

I am getting the following error message, if I send invalid `email`

```
{
  "error": "E_VALIDATION",
  "status": 400,
  "summary": "1 attribute is invalid",
  "model": "User",
  "invalidAttributes": {
    "email": [
      {
        "rule": "email",
        "message": "`undefined` should be a email (instead of \"vishnu@ad\", which is a string)"
      }
    ]
  },
  "Errors": {
    "email": [
      {
        "rule": "email",
        "message": "Provide valid email address"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

As you see the error message, I am getting both `invalidAttributes` and `Errors`. How to remove `invalidAttributes`?

How should I configure in my sails app to remove `invalidAttributes`?

Comment: You can remove it from the error in the *responses/badRequest.js* or any other response file - check if the data is an instance of Error, and if it is an `E_VALIDATION`, just set `invalidAttributes` to `null` or `delete` it completely.

Comment: Removing `invalidAttributes` for every request might not be good. There must be some configuration to remove that.

Comment: Why should there be? That's how Waterline tells you what's wrong with your data. Even if *sails-hook-validation* did provide a configuration option, it would be doing the very same thing I just proposed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify badRequest.js in response folder.

For example :

````
```//remove unnecessary keys if debug is false
  if(process.env.APP_DEBUG === 'false'){
    delete data.stack;
    delete data.rawStack;
    delete data.details;
    delete data.message;
    delete data.model;
    delete data._e;
    delete data.reason;
  }```
````